# Add brackets and comma

Tags: notepad++

If I have the numbers in two lines :-

```
2   3   5   47  60  64  75  98  
3   4   6   48  61  65  76  99
```

I want to add **" [ "** at the beginning of each line and add **" ] "** at the end of each line and also add a comma between the numbers to be like:-

```
[2,3,5,47,60,64,75,98],
[3,4,6,48,61,65,76,99],
```

I have tried adding **" [ "** at the beginning using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> → find what **^** &rar Replace with **" [ "** but the rest I do not know

Comment: Search mode 'Regular expression' should be selected. Then for '[' at the beginning of lines, you can write 'Find what' as '^' and 'replace with' as "[".  Then for commas in between numbers -    'Find what ' can be [0-9]* and 'replace with' "$&,". For removing the trailing "," and adding "],", you can have 'Find what as ",$" and 'replace with' as "],".

Answer (score 1):

RegEx replace:

[image: Notepad++ RegEx replace]

```
^([\d ]+[\d]+)[ ]*$
```

with

```
[\1],
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch the search mode to "Regular expression" and then perform these two search & replace operations:

Replace beginning and end of lines (including trailing whitespace):
Search: `^(.+?)\s*$`
Replace: `[\1],`

Replace separating whitespace:
Search `\s+`
Replace: `,`

Tools like [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) can help you figure out regular expressions.